# How to show time-picker top of input field

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap

I have a **time-picker** in HTML that is coming below of text field.
I want to show it on top of the **text box** field.

[image]

Comment: Please refer which plugin you are using also, @Pradeep

Comment: timepicki.js and timepicki.js

Answer (score 1):

Hey bud I think this may help, I know this is an old post but hopefully it will help those who come acrrossed looking for an answer much like I did.

Bootstrap's clockpicker offers varies options to customize the look and feel as well as functionality to your clockpicker.

in your javascript where you are initializing your clockpicker you will want to add this

```
placement: 'top',
```

a full initialization example would be like so:

```
$('#cp1').clockpicker({
            placement: 'top',
            autoclose: true,
            twelvehour: true,
            afterDone: function () {
                console.log("after done");
                console.log($('#cp1').val());
            }
        });
```

feel free to look around some documentation for more customization:
[clockpicker](https://weareoutman.github.io/clockpicker/)

Answer (score 0):

```
<input type="text" class="form-control timepicker" data-template="dropdown" data-show-seconds="true" data-default-time="11:25 AM" data-show-meridian="true" data-minute-step="5">
```

include following javascript which is actually a bootstrap component

```
<script src="js/bootstrap-timepicker.min.js"></script>
```

you can download following file from [here](https://jdewit.github.io/bootstrap-timepicker/)

Answer (score 0):

In screenshot it uses TimePicki js. See [timepicki github](http://senthilraj.github.io/TimePicki/).

Your input field.

```
<input type="text" name="timepicker" class="time_element" />
```

In javascript.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $(".time_element").timepicki();
});
```

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $(".time_element").timepicki();
});
```

```html
<link href="http://senthilraj.github.io/TimePicki/css/timepicki.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://senthilraj.github.io/TimePicki/js/timepicki.js"></script>

<input type="text" name="timepicker" class="time_element" />
```

Answer (score 0):

Please use this.
orientation: "top"

Comment: <script src="../../js/timepicki.js"></script>

Comment: <link href="../../css/timepicki.css" rel="stylesheet" />
 <script src="../../js/timepicki.js"></script>

Comment: i have used above plugins  ...im getting time picker but i want to change the position of time-picker....present it is coming down the input field... but i need it top